# Why are both conditions wrong?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem  with my code these 2 conditions aren't True. In fact, I have a Python background and they seem right for me. I hope anyone could help me solving this problem.
Thanks for your Time !

```
    char cArray[12] = "Hello World";

    char* pcVal = &cArray[2];

    if (cArray[2] == "l"){}

    if ((*pcVal) == "l"){}
```

Comment: Note: C programmers typically write `char *pcVal` rather than `char* pcVal`. It becomes important when you write something like `char* aptr, bptr;` (in which `bptr` is intended to be a pointer to char but is actually declared as a char because the asterisk binds to `aptr` rather than to `char`).

Comment: If you enable compiler warnings, the compiler will be yelling at you for comparing incompatible types.

Comment: @Cheatah yes, though newcomers to C aren't really all that aware of warnings.

Comment: The key thing, anyway, is that Python really does not have anything equivalent to char. It simply has, instead, a 1-character string which, of course *is* comparable to another string, whereas C has a real char type which is not comparable to a char array (aka string). Python also, of course, supports numerous string quote types (single, double, triple).

Comment: @jarmod Which is why I mention it, because honestly, nobody should compile without these warnings, unless they knew exactly what they were doing.

Comment: @Cheatah 100% agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a char with a string literal.

You need to use 'l'

char cArray[12] = "Hello World";

```
char* pcVal = &cArray[2];

if (cArray[2] == 'l'){}

if ((*pcVal) == 'l'){}
```

Comment: Didn't know that there is a difference between " and ' .

Comment: Yes -- There's a huge difference. 
"   is for strings, aka a series of characters that are then terminated by a null character.    So, "l"  actually is the character set, {'l', '\0'}       You should look up C-Strings online.